# jquery - How do i set the heights for each set of child divs within each container div?

Tags: jquery, css, class, height, parent-child

I have a number of containers (class="sidebox") with child divs each with varying amounts of content.

On some occasions I want the child divs to each be 100% height of the parent div, sometimes to add a vertical separator style.

To do this I add a class of `cfull` to the child divs and `vcon` to the container with the class of 'sidebox'.

Then call a jquery function:

```
var y = $('.cfull').parent('div.vcon').height();
    $(".cfull").height(y) ;
```

This perfectly when there is only one instance on  and sets it's children div height to the height of the sidebox.

If I add a second `sidebox vcon` in the html and give one of it's child divs additional content. The second sidebox child divs get the height set from the first instance of the sidebox

How do I set the heights for each set of child divs in a `class="sidebox vcon"` container div?

I hope that makes sense.

Here's my working example so far, you'll see the second sidebox children have the `style="height:#px"` from the first sidebox

http://bit.ly/jqueryheightissue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're doing is called implicit iteration. When you do this:

```
$('.cfull').height(y);
```

... what you're doing is setting all `.cfull` elements to only one value of height (the current value of `y`).

You want to iterate through each element explicitly, maybe by using `.each()`.

```
$('.cfull').each(function () {

    var self = $(this),
        container = self.parent('div.vcon');

    self.height(container.height());

});
```

However, you should be able to do what you're trying to achieve using just plain CSS. Have you tried doing something like this?

```
.cfull {
    height : 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that's worled perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through all of the elements with a class of `.cfull`. Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/QpEgX/5/

```
$('.cfull').each(function() {
    var y = $(this).parent('div.vcon').height();
    $(this).height(y) ;
});
```

Comment: While I see @Richard got a correct answer down first, I am not sure why I got voted down for an answer that works perfectly well.

Comment: Perhaps because there's already the same solution :)
If it's about points I'll give you a vote. What is right is right I don't care it's the same :)

Comment: Might have been because of an edit. Maybe a prior solution you submitted was wrong?

Comment: Perhaps, can't help you with that. I don't like down-votes, people should be more careful with them

Comment: ... doubling back, I realized that I was the one who downvoted. Sorry mate. I remember an earlier version being incorrect. Let me see if I can correct that now that this is rectified.

Answer (score 0):

```
var height = 0;
$('.cfull').each(function () {
  height = $(this).parent('div.vcon').height();
  $(this).height(height);
});
```